# What CAD software is used to design and manufacture projected capacitive touchscreens?

Tags: capacitive, touchscreen, cad, touch-panel

I am looking to learn more about how projected capacitive (PCAP) touchscreens are designed and made, specifically with laser ablation. What kind of CAD software is used to create layered drawings for the different manufacturing steps and what do the layers in the image below mean for the fabrication of the PCAP touchscreen.

[image: Layers for manufacturing a projected capacitive sensor]

Comment: your question is not about electronics design ... it belongs at https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions .... i would guess that not all PCAP screen manufacturers use the same software ... I would venture a further guess, and say that some of them use Solidworks